# Derivation of Stokes Formula using stream function

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, viscosity

I need help with derivation of Stokes Formula. I have found derivation on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_law), but I don’t know how can I get from equation (1) to equation (2). How to get from stream function to drag force.

$$ \psi = -\frac{1}{2}ur^2 \left[1-\frac{3}{2}\frac{R}{\sqrt{r^2+z^2}}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{R}{\sqrt{r^2+z^2}}\right)^3 \right] \tag{1}$$
$$ \mathbf{\sigma} = \frac{3\mu u}{2R}\mathbf{e}_z \tag{2}$$

Can you help me, please :)?

Comment: Welcome to this site.  It would be appreciated if you show what you have tried already to solve the problem. And the preferred way here to show formulas is [MathJax](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation). 
Please use it next time.

Comment: Have you used the stream function to calculate the velocity components in the radial and axial directions?

Comment: I transformed stream function into Cartesian coordinates, in order to calculate velocity components. Because I thought, that I will need stress tensor of viscous fluid. 
Than I calculated surface integral of stress tensor (surface of sphere. Using Gauss theorem, I converted it to volume integral of divergence of tensor. But my result was 0 after integration. 
So I have to be mistaken.

Comment: Try doing it in spherical coordinates, and don't forget to also include the pressure as part of the stress tensor.  I think that Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot has what you are looking for.

Comment: @ChetMiller Thanks for materials. But I don't really understand why should I calculate with normal stress. I thought, that in the Stokes law only tangential stresses are included. Can you explain it to me, please :)?

Comment: The pressure exerts a compressive stress normal to the surface of the sphere, and this normal stress has a component in the axial direction.  Also, the pressure on the leading half is higher than the pressure on the trailing half.  So there is a net axial force from the pressure (over and above that from the viscous shearing stress).

Comment: @ChetMiller Thanks.
Can I have one more ques
I have expression for dp/dr from Navier-Stokes in spherical coordinates. So I need to know what the pressure is, in order to integrate pressure around the surface of the sphere.

Comment: We have dP = (some function)*dr
In the papers they found pressure expression by integrating this equation on interval [R; infinite].
And I don't know why. Because I would rather use indefinite integral to solve the expression of pressure.
Thanks ;)

Comment: See Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot, Transport Phenomena to see the complete solution in terms of the stream function and pressure.